# Null value for Display.getInstance().getUdid() method on android tablets

Tags: codenameone

My requirement to get Unique deviceId with andriod tablets and ipads. for this I have used following code.

```
 Display.getInstance().getUdid();
```

Its working with my mobile and ipad. Its give me null value on running with andriod tablet with OS version 4.0.4.

Note : My tablet doesn't have SIM. I have used Samsung Verizon tablet.

While I am checking with tablet setting I have found Development Device ID. So could you please help how to get the unique id or development Device ID on andriod tablet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getUdid is not 100% reliable and some vendors are simply not implementing this.
You can get the android id which is more reliable.

Display.getInstance().getProperty("androidId", "");